# Setting up environment - $GOPATH

Tags: vim, go

I have defined my `$GOPATH` to be `$HOME/go` and when using vim-go, it has installed several binaries (using :GoInstallBinaries) into that folder. Now the structure is similar to:

```
--go/
----bin/
------ list of binaries

----pkg/
------linux_amd64
--------- list of other directories

----src/
------github.com
--------several other directories, similar with ones below
------golang.org
------gopg.in
```

I'm confused now where to start my own project within this structure? Say I wanted to create my own project virtual_tree, from what I understand it should be under src. But should that be inside of github.com? Where should my project go? Do I need to use `pkg/` for anything? I understand that `bin/` contains the executable for the project.

Thanks!

Comment: Read (and follow) https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Organization.

Comment: It's just a simple question, do I want to make a project **go get**-able ? if yes you should follow the hierarchy in your GOPATH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should follow the convention of `$GOPATH/src/REPOSITORY_PROVIDER/USERNAME/PROJECT`. So, if your `virtual_tree` project resides in github, then you should locate it in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/naz/virtual_tree`.
2. The `pkg` directory contains the compiled packages. Within that directory a sub-directory that describes the target architecture is created and that mirrors the source directories.

Read more on:

https://dave.cheney.net/2014/12/01/five-suggestions-for-setting-up-a-go-project

https://www.goinggo.net/2013/07/how-packages-work-in-go-language.html

Comment: It's more like `$domain/$pathname`. If you use GitHub, this means `$provider/$username/$project`, but this is in no way enforced or even "recommended" as such. e.g. I use my own domain for packages which doesn't follow this convention.